# How to change the password in windows without knowing the current password?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 administrator Password lost! How can I login windows 7 without password?](https://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password)

Hey guys
I want to change some password of any pc with out knowing their current password.
i know of using command prompt
using net users..

but is there any other way to change the password using some other technique?

i don't know proper but one of my friend changed my password using regedit...
and i know we can do this after some one had login but is there any way to change without log in.

btw i am using win 7.

thanks in advance

---

UPDATE:

First we will look at the link which u have given.....

all the links had one similar situation which is.... they are trying to logged in to the pc

ok?

In my situation, the PC is already logged into, and a password is not required for login.  This can happen if I am Administrator or not a limited user by using "net users" command from CMD.

And this I guess you know. Right?

So tell me now how this question is similar to links which you have given?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password http://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password

Comment: @Bobby,,,

this is not duplicate question....

i was asking about the all windows platform and i just gave my os info bcz i want to know about win 7 also...

i want to know about any technique that can be use to change the password and the pc may be logged in and i want to change the password from their.

so may be this is different question....

Comment: @Nitz: Mh...I'm still calling duplicate, here on SU are a ton of such questions: http://superuser.com/questions/132978/windows-recovery-console-forgot-password http://superuser.com/questions/132978/windows-recovery-console-forgot-password http://superuser.com/questions/147322/how-can-i-login-to-my-dads-pc-without-knowing-his-password-closed http://superuser.com/questions/95685/windows-7-administrator-password-lost-how-can-i-login-windows-7-without-password

Comment: Are you logged in as an administrator, or a normal user? (Admins can change the passwords of other accounts.)

Comment: @Bobby...
plz see the question again...
u might know now what i want....

and if u find it different then plz remove this [closed] kind of thing...

Comment: @Nitz: please don't remove the automatically inserted text.  if the question is reopened it will be removed then.

Comment: @Nitz: also, PLEASE DON'T POST ALL CAPS, IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING.

Comment: @Nitz: I don't get it...even if you're already logged in, my links do also apply (you can logoff or restart at any time). You wanna change the password, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

You can use their live CD to reset the password... it works on vista and windows 7.